# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a STMS. While am trying to model things out and try to add a new record for students table via:

```
stud = Student.create(:student_id => 1, :first_name => 'Jos', :last_name => 'Norton', :email => 'ss.norton@gmail.com', :birthday => '12/05/1995', :subjects => 'English', :username => 'samnorton05', :password => 'Grace02112')
```

I got an error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :enrolled_subjects in model Student
```

Here's the models I am using:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :enrolled_subjects

  def teacher_names
    self.teachers.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  has_many :admin_users
  has_secure_password
  self.primary_key = :student_id


  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at ASC") }
  scope :oldest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}

end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :students, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :admin_users
  has_secure_password

  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at ASC") }
  scope :oldest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :students, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :admin_users

  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}

end

class EnrolledSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord

  has_secure_password

  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at ASC") }
  scope :oldest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  # scope :search, lambda { |query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end
```

Basically I have 5 tables namely: Students, teachers, subjects, admin users and enrolled subjects. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Sorry I am a newbie here.

EDIT HERE ARE MY MIGRATION:

```
 create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "student_id", :auto_increment => true, :primary_key => true
    t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
    t.string "birthday"
    t.string "subjects"
    t.string "username", :limit => 25
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :teachers, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "teacher_id", :auto_increment => true, :primary_key => true
      t.string "first_name"
      t.string "last_name"
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.timestamps
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the enrolled_subjects as well, like:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # first you add the association to enrolled_subjects
  has_many :enrolled_subjects
  # then you add the associations you has through it
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrolled_subjects
  has_many :teachers, through: :enrolled_subjects

end
```

Comment: I tried it and it says **NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "English":String**

Comment: yeap! all of them, the model needs to know it has a `has_many` association with a model first to then be able to create another association through it.

Comment: this error you just got must be from something else.. i don't see it in the code you gave us

Comment: Let me share it my migration.

Comment: Ok shared my migration to you. I am still adding it via rails console **stud = Student.create(:student_id => 1, :first_name => 'Jos', :last_name => 'Norton', :email => 'ss.norton@gmail.com', :birthday => '12/05/1995', :subjects => 'English', :username => 'samnorton05', :password => 'Grace02112')**

Comment: Oh! I got it! `subjects` is expecting an array. it should be `:subjects => ['English']`

Comment: Why is that an array???? **stud = Student.create(:student_id => 1, :first_name => 'Sam', :last_name => 'Norton', :email => 'samuelnico.norton@gmail.com', :birthday => '12/05/1990', :subjects => ['English'], :username => 'samnorton05', :password => 'Grace0512')** I am still getting an error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Subject(#70152314297480) expected, got String(#70152284979280)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134231/discussion-between-rafael-costa-and-jim-carter).